# Dynamodb - scan map attribute with GraphQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm using GraphQL to scan a collection in dynamodb that looks like this:

```
{
  "config_name": "COLOR_PALETTE",
  "config_value": {
    "SHOW_CUSTOM_SUBSCRIPTION": "NO",
    "SHOW_DD_SUBSCRIPTION": "NO",
    "SHOW_GRADIENT_SUBSCRIPTION": "YES",
    "SHOW_SOLID_SUBSCRIPTION": "NO"
  }
}
```

I want to return "config_value" as key value pair. How I define AppSync schema and resolver to get "config_value" as key value pair ?

Answer (score 1):

If you set your schema up as follows:

```
type ConfigValues {
    SHOW_CUSTOM_SUBSCRIPTION: String!
    SHOW_DD_SUBSCRIPTION: String!
    SHOW_GRADIENT_SUBSCRIPTION: String!
    SHOW_SOLID_SUBSCRIPTION: String!
}

type Query {
    getConfigValues(configName: String!): ConfigValues
}

schema {
    query: Query
}
```

With a resolver on `getConfigValues` with a request mapping template of:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "GetItem",
    "key": {
        "config_name": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.configName),
    }
}
```

And a response mapping template of:

```
$util.toJson($ctx.result.config_value)
```

Performing the following query:

```
query {
  getConfigValues(configName: "COLOR_PALETTE") {
    SHOW_CUSTOM_SUBSCRIPTION
    SHOW_DD_SUBSCRIPTION
    SHOW_GRADIENT_SUBSCRIPTION
    SHOW_SOLID_SUBSCRIPTION
  }
}
```

Will have the response of:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getConfigValues": {
      "SHOW_CUSTOM_SUBSCRIPTION": "NO",
      "SHOW_DD_SUBSCRIPTION": "NO",
      "SHOW_GRADIENT_SUBSCRIPTION": "YES",
      "SHOW_SOLID_SUBSCRIPTION": "NO"
    }
  }
}
```

---

This answer assumes that your Primary partition key of your DynamoDB table is set to be `config_name`.